# Flutter - Calculate difference of two dates in months

Tags: date, flutter, timestamp

In **[Flutter](https://flutter-es.io/)** i have two *timestamps*.

I want to know difference of that. If it´is difference is more than **15 months** is incorrect, else is correct.

The code is

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch( from).difference(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(to)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

```
final date1 = DateTime(2019, 10, 12);
 final date2 = DateTime.now();
 double difference = double.parse(date2.difference(date1).inDays.toString());
if(difference < 456.25){
  print("correct");
}else{
  print("incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Some explanations could have done some good help

Answer (score 2):

If timestamp format is in Unix Timestamp, you need convert to DateTime like the code below:

```
  final date1 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1577836800 * 1000).toUtc(); // 01/01/2020 @ 12:00am (UTC)
  final date2 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1585699200 * 1000).toUtc(); // 04/01/2020 @ 12:00am (UTC)
  final difference = (date2.difference(date1).inDays / 30).floor();

  print(date1);
  print(date2);
  print(difference);
```